# Need help on compiling FFTW on visual studio

Tags: c++, fftw

I need to use the FFTW on visual studio 2008 with C++. I'm new to programming and I need your instruction on how to get it compiled and how to create the .lib files to use with my program. Thanks.

Comment: I could Google 'FFTW' and make an educated guess as to what you mean by it, but I shouldn't have to. You should provide a link.

Answer (score 2):

just follow the instructions

http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html

and then if you get specific questions, ask them here.

Comment: Hi, I have used a precompiled version of the FFTW I found. Now the problem is the following line is producing an error in visual studio. "p = fftw_create_plan(940800, 1, FFTW_ESTIMATE);"   And here is the error message ".\SoundPlayer.cpp(79) : error C3861: 'fftw_create_plan': identifier not found"

Answer (score 1):

http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Installation-on-non_002dUnix-systems.html#Installation-on-non_002dUnix-systems